# How can I quickly and easily measure one band in a sphere (or part of a sphere)?

Tags: 3d-printing, measurement

I'm modeling an object to print with a 3D printer. I'm working with a UV sphere and I've removed some bands at the top and the bottom half. What matters, in terms of size, is the band at the top, the one with all the vertices selected in this photo:

[image]

The height and diameter at the bottom either don't matter or aren't as important. How can I easily and quickly check the diameter of this one band at the top of the object? I do not want to just use a measure tool, since it can be hard to get a precise measurement with it. Since I'll be resizing, then checking, then resizing until I get it just right, I would really like to find a way to do this quickly and with minimal steps.

Comment: hmmm.. while the loop is selected you could press `P` and choose `selection` which would create a new object with that ring. `tab` out of edit mode and select the new object ring and press `N` in object mode. Then under `Item` tab you can see the dimensions of this ring.

Comment: That works. I leave the tab with "Item Information" open anyway. (Sorry, don't know the right terms for that!) That shows the information right away, then I can undo selecting the new item and making it a separate item. It'll be interesting if there's anything quicker.

Comment: actually doing the measurement tool is quite accurate, you can snap the ends of the measurement tool line using `Ctrl` while draggin, you can snap the ends to the vertices on opposite ends.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Well, daggonit! Amazing all the little things I just do not know about this program - did not know you could snap measurement like that!

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I saw you had an answer with a Python script, but the measurement trick does it. I've been using it for the past week to do quick measurements, but had no idea you could snap with `Ctrl`. If you want to write that as an answer, I'll select it.

Comment: alright, i added the measuring tool with the Ctrl snapping functionality in my answer. I had to re-edit the answer of the script coz i realized that you need to tab back into object mode and then back into edit mode whenver you make a change for the change to effect. and then you can run the script again

Comment: Speaking generally, you may also find the [3D Print Toolbox](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/3d_print_toolbox.html) helpful. You may find showing [Measurement](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/display/overlays.html#measurement) statistics such as Edge Length helpful as well.

Comment: @Mentalist Thank you!

Comment: No problem. Also, pay attention to object scale. If your object is scaled to anything other than `1.0, 1.0, 1.0` the measurements taken locally inside Edit Mode won't reflect what you see in the viewport globally. So generally keep objects scaled to 1 unless there's a specific reason to do otherwise. So after scaling them, **Apply Scale** and their new size will become their "true" size at a scale of 1. Lots of people use Blender for 3D printing, so the best advice I can offer is to start on a YouTube tutorial marathon. Don't worry about trying to *learn* everything, so much as *familiarize*.

Comment: @Mentalist Good point! I learned that early on and am used to resetting the scale, rotation, and location (all transforms) regularly with everything I'm working on. I ran into a lot of problems before I started doing that. I do find, for some procedures, it helps to be able to use the scale while making changes, but once I get to a certain point, I know I have to apply all the transforms. I'm glad to hear I'm not the only one using Blender for printing - there are a number of 3D things I want to do and it makes sense to use 1 program for all of them. That includes printing and CNC work.

Comment: You may want to add cad transforms to you add-on list great for measurements https://blender-archipack.gumroad.com/l/nQVcS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you open the *System Console* by going into menu *Window* -> *Toggle System Console*. Go to the *Scripting Tab* and create New text file and paste the script. While you have selected the loop you want to measure, click the *Run Script* button. You will see the output in the *system console*.

[image]

```
import bpy
import math

obj = bpy.context.active_object 
circumference = 0

edges = [e for e in obj.data.edges if e.select == True]
verts = obj.data.vertices
for edge in edges: 
    circumference += (verts[edge.vertices[0]].co - verts[edge.vertices[1]].co).length
 
print("diameter = ", circumference / math.pi)
```

**NOTE**: Make sure you tab out into *Object mode* and tab back into *Edit Mode* whenever you make a change before running the script again.

Actually doing the measurement tool is quite accurate, you can snap the ends of the measurement tool line using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while dragging, you can snap the ends to the vertices on opposite ends.

Answer (score 5):

You could enable the *Curve Tools* addon, duplicate and convert your edge loop to curve, select it in *Edit* mode, go into the *N panel > Edit > Curve Info*, click on *Length*:

[image]